# Не проверяет текст

Tags: java, android

Сделал условие на проверку, но почему то срабатывает лишь конечный способ. То есть, можно посылать с 2 пустыми строчками, а мне надо, чтобы проверялись  все три строки.

В чем ошибка?

```
if (textname.getText().length() == 0){
    textname.setError("Заполните Пустое Поле");
}
if (textsoname.getText().length() == 0){
    textsoname.setError("Заполните Пустое Поле");
}
if (texttel.getText().length() == 0){
    texttel.setError("Заполните Пустое Поле");
}

else {
//и если все поля заполнены применить этот метод
```

Comment: шо то я не до конца въехал в чем проблема? Ваш код выглядит правдоподобно, исходя из того что я вижу... Если какое то условие не отрабатывает - значит текущее состояние не соответствует условию.

Comment: методы textname и textsoname отправляются не заполненными тоесть можно написать только texttel и отправить

Comment: Не надо оборачивать ява-код в снипеты - они ничего не делают и только мешают

Comment: использоать boleeanŞ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто сделайте метод:

```
private void isTextFilled(TextView checkedTextView) {
    if (checkedTextView.getText().length() == 0){
        checkedTextView.setError("Заполните Пустое Поле");
    }
}
```

И им проверяйте любые TextView.

```
private void checkUserData() {
    isTextFilled(textname);
    isTextFilled(textsoname);
    isTextFilled(texttel);
}
```

Comment: супер отет ) мне очень понраилось

Answer (score 3):

Так, к примеру:

```
if (textname.getText().length() == 0)
  {
       textname.setError("Заполните Пустое Поле");
        return;
  }
  if (textsoname.getText().length() == 0){
        textsoname.setError("Заполните Пустое Поле");
        return;
   }
  if (texttel.getText().length() == 0){
        texttel.setError("Заполните Пустое Поле");
        return;
   }


//и если все поля заполнены применить этот метод
```

Comment: else уже ненужен?

Comment: вы даете откат после нахождения и он так пргоходит все 3 метода